# how to get the key based on value in json using jquery

Tags: jquery, json

how to get the key based on value.
of i pass value as 'A' i should get the key 'Attributes'

```
{
    "Employees": {
        "Attributes": [
            "A",
            "V",
            "C",
            "ZZ",
            "D",
            "E",
            "F",
            "G",
            "H",
            "I",
            "J"
        ],
        "Both": [
            "XXX",
            "YYY"
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you considered using lodash (or underscore)? If this  is a frequent lookup in your code, it might be worth to create and inverted data structure: http://devdocs.io/lodash/index#invert

Comment: What code have you written so far to try to get this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try utilizing `Object.keys`, `Array.prototype.filter`

```js
var data = {
    "Employees": {
        "Attributes": [
            "A",
            "V",
            "C",
            "ZZ",
            "D",
            "E",
            "F",
            "G",
            "H",
            "I",
            "J"
        ],
        "Both": [
            "XXX",
            "YYY"
        ]
    }
};

var q = "A";

var res = Object.keys(data.Employees).filter(function(val, key) {
  return data.Employees[val].indexOf(q) !== -1
})[0];

console.log(res);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
var data={
    "Employees": {
        "Attributes": [
            "A",
            "V",
            "C",
            "ZZ",
            "D",
            "E",
            "F",
            "G",
            "H",
            "I",
            "J"
        ],
        "Both": [
            "XXX",
            "YYY"
        ]
    }
};
var searchValue="A";
for(var i in data.Employees){
   if(data.Employees[i].indexOf(searchValue)>-1){
      console.log(i);
      break;
   }
}
```